# Moving a sprite to click location and stop there PIXIJS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

This simple game makes a sprite move around to the position a user clicks. I got it working that the sprite moves to the location, but I need to make it stop at the click location. This code makes the sprite only stop at the click location when the sprite moves towards the bottom right corner. How do I fix this to make it always stop at the click location?

```
var Container = PIXI.Container,
autoDetectRenderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer,
loader = PIXI.loader,
resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
Sprite = PIXI.Sprite;

var stage = new PIXI.Container(),
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(1000, 1000);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

PIXI.loader
  .add("animal.png")
  .load(setup);

var rocket, state;

function setup() {

  //Create the `tileset` sprite from the texture
  var texture = PIXI.utils.TextureCache["animal.png"];

  //Create a rectangle object that defines the position and
  //size of the sub-image you want to extract from the texture
  var rectangle = new PIXI.Rectangle(192, 128, 32, 32);

  //Tell the texture to use that rectangular section
  texture.frame = rectangle;

  //Create the sprite from the texture
  rocket = new Sprite(texture);
  rocket.anchor.x = 0.5;
  rocket.anchor.y = 0.5;
  rocket.x = 50;
  rocket.y = 50;
  rocket.vx = 0;
  rocket.vy = 0;

  //Add the rocket to the stage 
  stage.addChild(rocket);

  document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    rocket.clickx = event.clientX;
    rocket.clicky = event.clientY;
    var x = event.clientX - rocket.x;
    var y = event.clientY - rocket.y; 

    rocket.vmax = 5;
    var total = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    var tx = x/total;
    var ty = y/total;
    rocket.vx = tx*rocket.vmax;
    rocket.vy = ty*rocket.vmax;
  });

  state = play;
  gameLoop();
}

function gameLoop() {

  //Loop this function at 60 frames per second
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  state();

  //Render the stage to see the animation
  renderer.render(stage);
}

function play(){
    rocket.x += rocket.vx;  
    rocket.y += rocket.vy;
    if(rocket.x >= rocket.clickx){
        if(rocket.y >= rocket.clicky){
            rocket.x = rocket.clickx;
            rocket.y = rocket.clicky;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your sprite has the velocity 5. Then let's just check out the distance between the sprite and the stop position. Whenever it's less than 5, make it stop at the position.

```
function play(){
    var dx = rocket.x - rocket.clickx;
    var dy = rocket.y - rocket.clicky;

    if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= 5) {
        rocket.x = rocket.clickx;
        rocket.y = rocket.clicky;
    }
    else {
        rocket.x += rocket.vx;
        rocket.y += rocket.vy;
    }
}
```

You can modify the `if` statement like below to avoid `Math.srqt` call.

```
    if ((dx * dx + dy * dy) <= (5 * 5)) {
```